# How to create a single SSL server certificate for domain AND www subdomain by the XCA tool

Tags: ssl-certificate

I use XCA (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) for generating and managing server and client certs and keys.

But there is one thing I don't really understand:

How can I create a single certificate for both my domain and www subdomain. e.g.

- Common Name/Domain: alf-on.com
- Subdomain: www.alf-on.com

What are the correct settings in XCA to work properly on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Create CSR as usual for the base domain, and fill all domains as DNS names in `X509v3 Subject Alternate Name` field (Extensions tab). Some browsers (eg. IE), if they are validating a SAN certificate, they are ignoring Subject CN field. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935369/ssl-how-do-common-names-cn-and-subject-alternative-names-san-work-together